# Show that $a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Assume that $p$ and $q$ are distinct add primes such that $p-1\mid q-1$. If $\gcd(a,pq)=1$ ,show that: $$a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$

I have tried as follows:
$$a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \quad \text{and} \quad a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
$$\implies a^{(q-1)(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{q} \quad \text{and} \quad a^{(q-1)(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
$$\implies a^{(q-1)(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$
But then I am stuck - please help.

Comment: Damn, I lost the type-off this time. But hint: Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember that you are told that $p-1$ divides $q-1$. Note that you have not yet used this hypothesis. That suggests that you should *really* try to use it somehow.

Since $p-1$ divides $q-1$, then there exists $k$ such that $q-1 = k(p-1)$. That means that, since $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, then
$$1 \equiv 1^k \equiv (a^{p-1})^k \equiv a^{(p-1)k} = a^{q-1}\pmod{p}.$$

So now you have $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ *and* $a^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $p-1\mid q-1$ means that $q-1=k(p-1)$ for some $k$. Thus, 
$$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$$
implies that
$$a^{q-1} = a^{k(p-1)} = (a^{p-1})^k\equiv 1^k= 1\bmod p.$$
Now use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

You know that:

$a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ mod $p$

but $(p-1)|(q-1)$ so this means that

$a^{q-1} \equiv 1$ mod $p$.

Now you may use the Chinese remainer theorem with your first congruence to tell you that

$a^{q-1} \equiv 1$ mod $pq$

Answer (score 0):

Go easier and use FLT (Fermat's Little Theorem).

$gcd(a,pq)=1 \implies$
$\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c} gcd(a,p)=1 \\ gcd(a,q)=1 \end{array}\right. \implies a^{p-1}\equiv1~(mod~p) $.

Now, using that $p-1|q-1$ (i.e. $\exists~x\in\mathbb Z:x(p-1)=q-1$), we can reach the following statement:

$a^{p-1}\equiv a^{q-1}\equiv 1~(mod~p) \implies \left\lbrace\begin{array}{c} p|a^{q-1}-1\\ q|a^{q-1}-1 \end{array}\right. \implies pq|a^{q-1}-1 \implies a^{q-1}\equiv 1~(mod~pq)$

Just take care that we can do the first implication of the second line because $gcd(p,q)=1$.